# How can I add Black theme to MFC dialogue based application?

Tags: mfc

I tried manually to add colour to dialogue using OnCtlColor but area behind static text and labels remain unchanged .so is there any way to add color to whole dialogue equally or else how Can I add black theme to dialogue?
Thanks in advance!